# Directive that wraps URL with link tags

Tags: angularjs

I have a text with new line separator and urls:

`first row\nFind me at http://www.example.com and also\n at http://stackoverflow.com`.

I want to write directive that takes string and wrap URLs with `<a></a>`

I have this HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="row in note_value.split('\n') track by $index"
               wm-urlify="row"
               style="display: inline-block;" 
               >
            </p>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.note_value = "first row\nFind me at http://www.example.com and also\n at http://stackoverflow.com";

});
```

I started to write directive that should take text and return *urlfied* text:

```
app.directive('wmUrlify',['$parse',
      function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
          scope: true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

           function urlify(text) {
                var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
                return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
                    return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
                })

            }

           var text = $parse(attrs.wmUrlify)(scope);

            var html = urlify(text);

          element[0].inneHtml(html)

        }
        };
      }]);
```

But it does't work, i get error:

> TypeError: element[0].html is not a function

The expected HTML should be like:

```
     <p>first row</p>
     <p>Find me at <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">http://www.example.com</a> and also</p>
     <p> at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com</a></p>
```

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pfz0xj7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your last line to `element.html(html)`and it worked

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found solution:

I need to call `angular.element` on append html:

```
 .... 
 angular.element(element[0]).html(html)
 ....
```

Fixed [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd2n4tLo/)

Thanks anyways,

Comment: instead of `angular.element(element[0]).html(html)`, you get the same result with `element.html(html)` (as proposed in my answer). 
The point is the `element` argument from `link()` is already an angular element, so you could apply [Angular jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) directly